# When the num_rows is null in all_tab_statistics in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to know when the num_rows is set to null in all_tab_statistics table.

One of my queries is taking a bad plan because the table is having num_rows as blank.

The table is partitioned. So the table is freshly created and ideally, it should have 0 rows. What could be the reason for this and how to avoid this.

Also when we are running the job on the freshly created table which is having blank num_rows(in stats) the rows got inserted in between the process is more than 0 but since we can't analyze the table between the process it took wrong plan (because of blank num_rows)

Comment: Can you show the plan your optimizer is taking?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a table

```
CREATE table empty
(
  dummy NUMBER
);
```

First time running this query gives

```
select table_name, num_rows from sys.all_tab_statistics where owner = 'HR' and table_name = 'EMPTY';
```

```
TABLE_NAME  NUM_ROWS
----------  --------
EMPTY       <NULL>
```

Then I inserted some rows

```
INSERT INTO empty SELECT SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES;
COMMIT;
```

And got the same result

```
TABLE_NAME  NUM_ROWS
----------  --------
EMPTY       <NULL>
```

Running this statement populated the row for `EMPTY` table in all_tab_statistics

```
ANALYZE TABLE empty COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

I got

```
TABLE_NAME  NUM_ROWS
----------  --------
EMPTY       107
```